# PHP Require method doesn't show any CSS style

Tags: php, html, css

I'm recently doing a website for a school project. In order to organize my work, I create a tree folder that keeps all the work organized. It is similar like this:

- Back-Office

  - Pages

    - Home

      - home_test1.php
      - home_test2.php
      - home_test3.php
    - Login

      - Folder_Login

        - login.php
        - logout.php
  - Resources

    - CSS

      - style_home.css
      - style_navbar.css
      - style_footer.css
    - JS

      - script_home.css
      - script_navbar.css
  - Sections

    - navbar.php
    - footer.php

After all, with the `require()` method available in PHP, I want to call the "navbar.php" file to the "home_test1.php", "home_test2.php" and "home_test3.php", but the CSS style that is connected with the file "navbar.php" ("style_navbar.php"), doesn't display.

I've tried to change the path of the CSS style in the file "navbar.php" when I `require()` to the other file ("home_test1.php") and the CSS style shows up, but wont display in other file with a different path. How can I make this work dynamically? Sorry for long post and bad English grammar.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should include all relevant code to showcase the issue you're having

Comment: what path of css file you include

Comment: Before: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/CSS/style_navbar.css">` After: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Resources/CSS/style_navbar.css">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your css and js files with absolute path instead of relative path

```
$dir = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $dir.'/resources/css/style_home.css'; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Without physically seeing you code it is quite hard to debug however there is an "obvious" answer that I'll suggest as a starting point.

The important thing to remember is that PHP and HTML are processed in completely different places. PHP executes on the server and should be used to build a full HTML "document" which it gives to the client/browser. The client/browser then reads the document provided and renders it according to HTML standards.

Calling `require()` will tell PHP to get the file and slot its contents directly where it was called and as it is a CSS file it will need to sit within the `style` tags. With a lot of modern browsers, if you use `require` on a file outside of the `html` tags, the content will be dumped at the top of the screen or simply ignored due to invalid syntax.

Alternatively if you would like to simply use tell the browser to include the CSS file, you could use the good old method of using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/file">`. It's good to know when and when not to use PHP.

PS: You have `.css` files in your JS directory.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It's not what I actually want, but you give me a good explanation! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: No problem! Hopefully it will be useful to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, there is a global variable containing various details related to the server. It's called `$_SERVER.` It contains also the root:-

> $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

```
<?php

   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path.= '/Resources/CSS/style_navbar.css';?>" />

?>
```